# How to handle package installation errors?

Tags: python, package

I am trying to install a package named 'sparsesvd' in python but I am getting the following error:

```
Collecting sparsesvd
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/d9/c2545987871e27cad5969799a1d45073321a2904ac4dcb18bc0f1fe16ecc/sparsesvd-0.2.2.tar.gz
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.6.0 in c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from sparsesvd) (1.2.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from sparsesvd) (0.29.6)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from scipy>=0.6.0->sparsesvd) (1.16.2)
    Installing collected packages: sparsesvd
      Running setup.py install for sparsesvd: started
        Running setup.py install for sparsesvd: finished with status 'error'
        Complete output from command C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\sparsesvd\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wd31zika\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        cythoning sparsesvd.pyx to sparsesvd.c
        C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\sparsesvd\sparsesvd.pxd
          tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
        warning: sparsesvd.pxd:7:31: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
        warning: sparsesvd.pxd:7:40: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
        building 'sparsesvd' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

        ----------------------------------------

    Command "C:\Users\IronMaiden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\sparsesvd\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wd31zika\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\sparsesvd\
```

Answer (score 0):

The error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

did you install it?

Edit: the original link is not working. Try this instead : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Yes I did not it gives this error

error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include /Tcsparsesvd.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\sparsesvd.obj" failed with exit status 127

Comment: I am not sure I got your answer about the visual cpp build tools. But If you installed it, then when you got that error, during installing the package ? is that the full error message?

Comment: yes, I am getting the error after installing the visual cpp build tools

Comment: I would recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), becuase it contains many packages.

Answer (score 0):

**2022**-My problem got solved by installing the latest version of MS Visual Stdio. I don't have any good reason for why it worked, though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30993086)